# How to change normal sql php code to secure pdo?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to prevent SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Is this code secure since i am using mysql_real_escape_string and strip_tags
Is there any need to change to pdo ?
I am not able to convert the following code to pdo because its displaying cannot modify header .

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$link =mysql_connect($db_host,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($db_name);

$id= $_POST["uniqi"]; 
$comments= $_POST["comments"]; 
$comments= mysql_real_escape_string($comments);
$comments = strip_tags($comments);

$update = "UPDATE mastertable SET comments = '$comments' WHERE id_pk= '$id'";
mysql_query($update, $link);
mysql_close();
header('Location: http://www.xxxx.com/xxxxx/xxxx.php?cntmsg=Comment Updated');
?>
```

Comment: You should definitely convert this to PDO - the mysql extension [is being deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not safe code - your `$id` variable is not processed by your code.

```
$id= $_POST["uniqi"]; 
$id= mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$id = strip_tags($id);
```

Comment: @vascowhite - first part of the reply is the actual regarding code safety

Comment: @TudorConstantin $id is used in update statement

Comment: @Tom - yes, but you use the value that comes from the client (the browser) - it could send you dragons there like `'; DELETE FROM comments; SELECT '` instead of an id :)

Comment: so how can i make the above code sercure or to pdo >

Comment: process the `$id` variable the same way you do with `$comments`